# Division of Big Integers represented like string in c++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, biginteger, division

**EDIT:** Now a method ( division function) down below works correct!

I am working on division of Big Integers in c++. I have already written functions for addition and subtraction, but I am facing problems with division. 
Here is Big_Integer class:

```
big_int.h
 char toChar(int num)
class Big_Int
{
public:
    Big_Int();                
    Big_Int(const Big_Int&);  
    Big_Int(string);          
    Big_Int& operator=(const Big_Int&);
    Big_Int operator+(const Big_Int&);
    friend Big_Int difference(const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend Big_Int divide(const Big_Int&, long long);
    friend  Big_Int operator - (const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend bool operator<(const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend bool operator>(const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend bool operator<=(const Big_Int& , const Big_Int&);
    friend bool operator>=(const Big_Int& , const Big_Int&);
    friend Big_Int operator/(const Big_Int&, long long);
    friend bool less_than(const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend bool less_or_eq(const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend bool operator==(const Big_Int&, const Big_Int&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& , const Big_Int&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, const Big_Int&);

private:
    string number;
};
```

Here is my division function:

```
Big_Int divide(const Big_Int& in, long long den)
{
    string w_dvt = in.number;
    int carry = 0;
    string dvt = 0;
    string result;

while (!(w_dvt.empty()))
{
    if ((w_dvt[0] == '0') && (carry == 0))
    {
        result += w_dvt[0];         
        w_dvt = w_dvt.substr(1);
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < w_dvt.size(); ++i)
        {
            dvt += w_dvt[i];
            if (stoi(dvt) >= den) break;
        }
                w_dvt = w_dvt.substr(i + 1);

        long long i_dvt = stoi(dvt);
        int res = i_dvt / den;
        carry = i_dvt%den;
        i_dvt = carry;
        dvt = to_string(i_dvt);
        result += toChar(res);
    }
}
return Big_Int(result);
} 
 Big_Int operator/(const Big_Int& in, long long den)
 {
     Big_Int res = divide(in, den);
     return res;
 }

char toChar(int num)
{
    char ch = '0'+ num ;
    return ch;
}
```

Here is main program:

```
int main()
{
    string num1, num2;
    cin >> num1;
    Big_Int i1(num1);
    cin >> num2;
    Big_Int i2(num2);
    Big_Int divs = i1 / 8;
    cout << divs << endl; 
}
```

It compiles well, but when i try to run it it aborts with a message:

```
"Expression: invalid null pointer"
```

I did some modifications to my program to eradicate that problem, but it still aborts with the same message. If anybody has any ideas regarding the problem with my code I would appreciate it.

Comment: `error C3861: 'toChar': identifier not found`

Comment: Run in a debugger to catch crashes, and help locate where they happen in your code. If you can't figure it out then at least tell us where in your code the crash happens, and the values of all involved variables.

Comment: @Christian Hackl I posted just a piece of my program, toChar is defined above.

Comment: @stacy_stacy: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Else we may assume that `toChar` starts up 10 different threads which run `main` concurrently and modify some static variables without locks.

Comment: A `friend` list like MM would have on facebook, but `operator+` is a member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scratching:

```
string dvt = 0;
```

putting:

```
string dvt /*= 0*/ ;
```

makes at least

```
int main()
{
    Big_Int divs = Big_Int("42") / 8;
    cout << divs << endl; 
}
```

run.

(I added trivial impls for  `Big_Int (string s)` and `operator<<`)

**EDIT**

A little explanation: A char* pointing to a zero-terminated empty c-string is **not** an - invalid - (char*)(0); It is a valid pointer that points to a (char)0.